# If I use the Google Drive SDK in my app is it possible to hide the saved data from the user?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to use the Google drive sdk to save data from my app in the user's own Google drive account. This will mean that the developers of the app (i.e. me) won't have access to sensitive data that the user is storing.

I have found some docs about how to do this (the app will be a Google app engine app) but I was wondering if I can lock this data or hide it completely so that a user can't go in and edit the data and possibly cause problems.

I know that Android apps that use Google drive do not leave any visible files that I can see when I go to my drive account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When [creating the file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert?hl=en), set the `hidden` label to True. This will hide the file from most user views. Note that it doesn't completely prevent the user from finding and modifying the file if they own it.

If you need the file to be uneditable by the owner, your app will need to own it and only grant the user view access.

Answer (score 0):

In [Google Play Services 4.3](https://developers.google.com/drive/release-notes), they added an "Application Folder." This is designed to allow applications to store data in a user's drive without allowing them to modify this data. It's available for [android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) and [web](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata), don't see it listed for iOS.